# Consecutive animations of component based on changing props

Tags: react-native, react-animated

I am trying to create a Snackbar-like status message component with a signature that looks like so:

```
<StatusMsg
 open={this.state.isOpen}
 message={this.state.msg}
 onRequestClose={someFunc}
 />
```

When "open" is set to true, then the message should animate onto the screen, stay there for a time period, then animate off again.

So, the code below works fine, EXCEPT in a fairly common use case: When the calling component sets a new message before the old one has animated off screen. In that case, the code below simply replaces the currently displayed message and uses the same timer.

Ideally, when a new message is added, that should cause the old message to animate off screen first, then animate in the new message. (I'd like to ensure it does this even if the new message text is the same as the old.)

I just can't seem to figure out how to do something like this. My best guess is that StatusMsg should actually be a factory for creating animated views that contain the messages, but I have no idea how to make that work. Specifically, how to make prior messages close themselves upon the creation of a new message.

```
class StatusMsg extends Component {
  state = { exited: false, moveHeightAnimated: new Animated.Value(HIDDEN_HEIGHT) }
  timerAutoHide = null;

  componentWillMount() {
    if (!this.props.open) {
      this.setState({ exited: true });
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.open) {
      this.show();
    }
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.open && this.state.exited) {
      this.setState({ exited: false });
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.open !== this.props.open) {
      if (this.props.open) {
        this.show();
      } else {
        clearTimeout(this.timerAutoHide);
      }
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearTimeout(this.timerAutoHide);
  }

  show() {
    const toValue = SHOW_HEIGHT;
    Animated.timing(this.state.moveHeightAnimated, {
        toValue,
        duration: 225,
        easing: Easing.bezier(0.0, 0.0, 0.2, 1),
    }).start(this.setAutoHideTimer);
  }

  hide() {
    const toValue = HIDDEN_HEIGHT;
    Animated.timing(this.state.moveHeightAnimated, {
        toValue,
        duration: 195,
        easing: Easing.bezier(0.4, 0.0, 1, 1),
    }).start(this.onFinishedHiding);
  }

  onFinishedHiding = () => {
    this.setState({ exited: true });
    if (this.props.onRequestClose) {
      this.props.onRequestClose();
    }
  }

  setAutoHideTimer = () => {
    if (!this.props.onRequestClose) {
      return;
    }

    clearTimeout(this.timerAutoHide);
    this.timerAutoHide = setTimeout(() => {
      if (!this.props.onRequestClose) {
        return;
      }

      this.hide();
    }, this.props.autoHideDuration || DEFAULT_AUTOHIDE_DURATION);
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.props.open && this.state.exited) {
      return null;
    }

    return (
      <Animated.View style={[styles.msgContainerStyle, { bottom: this.state.moveHeightAnimated }]} >
        <View style={styles.noticeContainerStyle}>
          <Text style={styles.msgTextStyle}>{this.props.message}</Text>
        </View>
      </Animated.View>
    );
  }
}
```